# Temporary Hold（一時保留）のステータスについて

Tags: paypal

PayPalの取引のステータスがTemporary Hold（一時保留）になるタイミングがわかる方いらっしゃいますか？

Answer (score 1):

主に以下の3つの状況でステータスが変わります。

1.PayPalのセキュリティモデルにより、当該トランザクションにレビューが必要と判断された場合
2.チャージバック時
3.異議申し立て時

システム的には、1の場合はDoExpressCheckoutPaymentコール時ですが、2、3についてはDoExpressCheckoutPaymentコール後の任意のタイミングで発生します（buyerの行動がトリガーとなります）。

リアルタイムでTemporary Holdをシステム的に処理する場合（ステータスが完了になった時点でなんらかの処理をするなど）はIPNに対応する必要があります。
（PayPal側でステータスを変更した場合は、IPNで通知されます）